# Does Micronaut have ablity to connect to ActiveMQ Artemis which supports the AMQP & MQTT protocols just like RabbitMQ?

Tags: micronaut, activemq-artemis

I want to use ActiveMQ Artemis as my message broker. Is there any client library to support that in Micronaut?

Anything similar to the [RabbitMQ](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#rabbitmq) config below?

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.micronaut.configuration</groupId>
    <artifactId>micronaut-rabbitmq</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

```yaml
rabbitmq:
    uri: amqp://user:pass@host:10000/vhost
    requestedFrameMax: 10
    requestedChannelMax: 10
    connectionTimeout: 5000
```

Answer (score 0):

Integration with ActiveMQ Artemis *is* supported via JMS, e.g.:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.micronaut.jms</groupId>
    <artifactId>micronaut-jms-activemq-artemis</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

```
micronaut:
  jms:
    activemq:
      artemis:
        enabled: true
        connection-string: 'tcp://host:port'
```

See [the documentation](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-jms/latest/guide/index.html) for all the details.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is no, however an external library that adds support for this would be welcome. You can look at any of the configurations for examples on how to implement something like that and if you have any questions, check out our [Gitter](https://gitter.im/micronautfw).